# How does one bypass SyntaxError when parsing code?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am using openpyxl to read an excel file that will have changing values over time. The following function will take string inputs from the excel sheets to make frames for Tkinter.

```
def make_new_frame(strng, frame_location, frame_name, frame_list):
    if not(frame_name in frame_list):
        frame_list.append(frame_name)
        exec("global %s" %(frame_name)) in globals()
        exec("%s = Frame(%s)"%(frame_name, frame_location))
```

.... etc.
The code itself is quite long but I think this is enough of a snapshot to address my problem.

Now this results in the following error while parsing:

> SyntaxError: function 'make_new_frame' uses import * and bare exec, which are illegal because it is a nested function

Everything in the code I included parsed and executed just fine several times, but after I added a few more lines in later versions in this function, it keeps spitting out the above error before executing the code. The error references the third line in the function, (which, I repeat, has been cleared in the past).

I added "in globals()" as recommended in another SO post, so that solution is not working.
There is a solution online [here](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Tutor-executing-dynamic-code-with-exec-td1681904.html) that uses setattr, which I have no idea how to use to create a widget without eventually using exec.
I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to bypass the error while parsing or provide an alternative means for a dynamically changing set of frame names.

Quick Note:

- I am aware that setting a variable as global in python is generally warned against, but I am quite certain that it will serve useful for my code

Edit 1: I have no idea why this was downvoted. If I have done something incorrectly, please let me know what it is so I can avoid doing so in the future.

Comment: 1: you did not provide sufficient code to recreate the error (I know it has to be a nested function to get that error)  2: please use a dictionary to store dynamic names instead of variables `space = {} ; space[frame_name] = Frame(frame_location)`

Comment: dynamically modifying the global scope from executing code that may come from other sources is a really bad idea.

Comment: (Truth be told: I tried to do the same thing before discovering the `dict` object type, it is actually what `globals()` returns)

Comment: Plus you are trying to break several lines from [the zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) mostly `Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.` and `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.` so if it tells you what you are trying to do is **illigal** there is probably a good reason.

Comment: Your code is not just hideous but also incomplete. The `SyntaxError` already tells you what you're doing wrong. I'm going to vote to close this.

Comment: There is almost certainly a better way to accomplish your task than to use exec. What is the _real_ problem you're trying to solve? If looks like you are trying to create dynamic variable names which is nearly always a very bad idea.

Comment: Read the posts in the link you provided, there are people who explain why your approach won't work and suggest much better ways to do it.

Comment: If there is a reason you are not simply using a dict instead, your question needs to explain it. If not, this should probably be closed, perhaps as "why isn't this code working".

Comment: @ Tadhg thank you for explaining my post's fallacy

Comment: @Charlie Clark, the syntax error did not pop up before, even though the same series of code was present, I say it in my post above. and calling the code hideous seems rather unnecessary and kind of personal- makes me not want to ask sincere questions, not sure if that is the culture on SO

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, thank you for your solution, I will try it. I mainly see your answers and have come to the conclusion that you're the expert on Tkinter so if you could point me to a resource you trust that can maybe enlighten me more on exec/Tkinter in general I would really appreciate it.
I do want to create dynamic variable names as the program will allow the user to add and remove elements. I'm not used to thinking in terms of lists and dicts, maybe it's time to shift that perspective, I don't even know why it's a bad idea-  I was hoping to find someone who would explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are asking for help with solution Y instead of asking for help on problem X.

If your goal is to create an unknown number of Frame objects based on external data, you can store references to the frame in a list or dictionary without having to resort to using `exec` and dynamically created variable names.

`exec` is a perfectly fine function, but is one of those things that you should never use until you fully understand why you should never use it.

Here's how to solve your actual problem without using exec:

```
frames = {}
def make_new_frame(strng, frame_location, frame_name, frames):
    if not(frame_name in frames):
        frames[frame_name] = Frame(frame_location)
    return frames[frame_name]
```

With that, you now have a dictionary (`frames`) that includes a reference for every new frame by name. If you had a frame named `"foo"`, for example, you could configure and pack it like this:

```
frames["foo"].configure(background="red", ...)
frames["foo"].pack(...)
```

If preserving the order of the frames is important you can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).